# Regular expression in Perl for G729A+B

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to Perl. I'm unable to do the regular expression match for the below fields.

I'm trying to match the pattern : G729A+B  coming in the log file which is coming in the below format.. What should be regular expression to match this?

```
2015/09/21 19:42:06 [DEBUG] [12401] : 
getDspResourceUtilization   : Total Compression:       900      1           0
2015/09/21 19:42:06 [DEBUG] [12401] : getDspResourceUtilization   : G729A+B:                 144      1           0
[12401] : getDspResourceUtilization   : G723.1:                  0        0           0
```

Comment: Could you please post your code so that we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

`/G729A\+B/` will match strings containing `G729A+B`.